# How to fix "The method 'raisedButton' isn't defined" error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, deprecated

I'm working on a Flutter tutorial in Android Studio and encountering the error:

> The method 'raisedButton' isn't defined for the class
> '_PomodoroState'.

I understand that this widget might be outdated or deprecated. Attempts like creating a separate class for the button and using the `stful` widget haven't resolved the issue.

**What I've tried:**

- Researched the `raisedButton` widget and realized it might be deprecated.
- Tried creating a separate class for the button.
- Used the `stful` widget to check if it would help.

**Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
// Other imports ... 

class _PomodoroState extends State<Pomodoro> {
  // ... other code ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        // ... other code ...

        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 28.0),
          child: raisedButton( // The error occurs here
            onPressed: _StartTimer,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            // ... other properties...
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
lib/main.dart:151:38: Error: The method 'raisedButton' isn't defined for the class '_PomodoroState'.
 - '_PomodoroState' is from 'package:pomodoris/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'raisedButton'.
                              child: raisedButton(
```

**Question:**
How can I resolve this error and use the appropriate replacement for `raisedButton` in my Flutter Pomodoro app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capitalize the R. It's `RaisedButton`, not `raisedButton`.

However, `RaisedButton` is depricated. Instead of

```
raisedButton(
   onPressed: _StartTimer,
   color: Colors.redAccent,
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
   ),
   child: Padding(
```

you want to use `ElevatedButton`. You also need to move your styling to the new style property, where you pass the color etc. into ElevatedButton.styleFrom() constructor.

```
ElevatedButton(
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.red,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
      ),
   ),
onPressed: _StartTimer,
child: Padding(
```

However...
This look is also depricated according to the Material Guidelines that Flutter follows. See how to make buttons look nice and modern here: https://material.io/components/buttons
All of the names are also the names of the widgets in Flutter. If you get stuck there, feel free to ask again!

Comment: Even with the capitalized “R” doesn't work, however with ElevatedButton, it works, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**RaisedButton is deprecated on the Latest flutter version. You can replace RaisedButton with ElevatedButton **

```
 ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('ElevatedButton'))
```

Answer (score 1):

RaisedButton is no longer use by Flutter new versions

instead you can use an Elevated button

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('login clicked');
            },
            child: Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: "Brand Bold"),
            ))
```